# Pygame WINDOWRESIZED black screen

Tags: python, pygame, resize

I'm trying to resize a window in pygame but only get a black screen. See the before and after pictures below. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *

pg.init()

yellow = (255, 255, 134)
grey = (142, 142, 142)

square_size = 100
width = 7 * square_size
height = 7 * square_size
radius = int(square_size / 2 - 10)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height), RESIZABLE)

screen.fill(grey)

pg.draw.circle(screen,yellow,(square_size,square_size),radius)

pg.display.flip()

while True:
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            print("quit game")
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if ev.type == pg.WINDOWRESIZED:
            width, height = screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()
    pg.display.flip()
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

You need to redraw the scene after resizing the window. I recommend redrawing the scene in each frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *

pg.init()

yellow = (255, 255, 134)
grey = (142, 142, 142)

square_size = 100
width = 7 * square_size
height = 7 * square_size
radius = int(square_size / 2 - 10)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height), RESIZABLE)
clock = pg.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:

    # limit the frames per second 
    clock.tick(100)

    # handle the events
    for ev in pg.event.get():
        if ev.type == pg.QUIT:
            print("quit game")
            run = False
        if ev.type == pg.WINDOWRESIZED:
            width, height = screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()
    
    # clear display
    screen.fill(grey)

    # draw scene
    pg.draw.circle(screen,yellow,(square_size,square_size),radius)

    # update the display
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```